# How to make ES6 Module exported function available in the dom?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, es6-modules

I am using ES6 Modules in Chrome. I have a simple front end app just using vanilla html,  JS, and material components for web.

In app.js I have

```js
import {
  slideToGetCode,
} from './animations.js';
```

in the module animations.js, I have:

```js
const slideToGetCode = () => {                                                                            
  setUsernameOnAccountRecovery();                                                                         

  setTimeout(() => {
    const loginContainerSlider = clearAnimationStates();                                                  
    loginContainerSlider.classList.add('slide-left-recover');                                             
  }, 250);                                                                                                
};


export {
  slideToGetCode,
};
```

In index.html, I have

```html
<script type="module" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="js/animations.js"></script>
<button "mdc-button" onclick="slideToGetCode()">Forgot Password?</button>
```

However, I get `(index):171 Uncaught ReferenceError: slideToGetCode is not defined` when I click on the button. How can I make `slideToGetCode()` available in the dom from the ES6 module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I honestly feel Forgot Password and any other button should be coming as component and not hard coded in `index.html` file.

However I think below should work. See suggested changes in `animations.js` file.

File `animations.js`.

```
const slideToGetCode = () => {                                                                            
  setUsernameOnAccountRecovery();                                                                         

  setTimeout(() => {
    const loginContainerSlider = clearAnimationStates();                                                  
    loginContainerSlider.classList.add('slide-left-recover');                                             
  }, 250);                                                                                                
};

window.slideToGetCode = slideToGetCode;
export {
  slideToGetCode,
};
```

File `index.html`

```
<script src="js/animations.js"></script>
<button "mdc-button" onclick="() => slideToGetCode()">Forgot Password?</button>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could also update `app.js` a la:

```
import {
  slideToGetCode,
} from './animations.js';

const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', sideToGetCode);
```

Which would allow you not to have to hang anything off of the `window` or put any event listeners in your HTML.